# How to get my text underneath the icon in the div

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I used to know how to do it but its been a long time now, does anyone know how to get my text underneath the icons. Its mandatory to use the fontawesome icons so you guys know.

[image]

i included a image which shows exactly what im talking about, and also if somebody has some experience with fontawesome, how do you get the round border around the icons.

thank you in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="nl-NL">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Hicham Stage Opdracht</title>

    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e27b2e5223.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/global.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="wrapper p-none">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Aanbod</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Over ons</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>


    <div class="wrapper white" style="min-height: 1000px;">

        <p style="color:dodgerblue;">Personenbus huren Zaandam<br/>

            <p>Snel een betaalbare personenbus huren in Zaandam voor een weekendje weg of een leuke activiteit met vrienden en familie. Bij Bert Jonk Autoverhuur is er altijd een personenbus die past bij uw wensen en hetgeen u gaat ondernemen. De personenbusjes zijn uit te breiden met diverse extra opties en alle huurprijzen zijn inclusief:</p>

        <p>•    WA-verzekering<br/>
            •   21% btw<br/>
            •   100 kilometer vrij rijden</p>

        <p>Wanneer u een personenbus huurt bij onze vestiging in Zaandam vragen we om een borgsom van € 250,-. Verder heeft u de mogelijkheid om het busje in overleg een dag van tevoren op te halen bij de verhuurlocatie. Bekijk hieronder ons aanbod personenbussen en reserveer direct uw ideale busje of bel naar <a href="tel:075 303 0619">075 303 0619<br/></a>.</p>

        <div><i id="search" class="fas fa-search fa-3x"><a>Artist First Last</a></i></div>
        <div><i id="calendar"  class="fas fa-calendar-alt fa-3x"><a>Artist First Last</a></i></div>
        <div><i id="car" class="fas fa-car fa-3x"><a>Artist First Last</a></i></div>
        <div><i id="thumbsup" class="fas fa-thumbs-up fa-3x"><a>Artist First Last</a></i></div>


    </div>


    <footer>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col6">
                    <h2>Lorem</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim.</p>
                </div>



                <div class="col3">
                    <h2>Meest bekeken</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Aanbod</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Over ons</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Autos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Vrachtwagens</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Bussen</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">iClicks</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="col3">
                    <h2>Adres</h2>
                    <p>Clicks Nederland BV<br/>
                    Zilverparkkade 64<br/>
                    8232 WK Lelystad</p>

                    <p>Telefoon: <a href="tel:0884254257">088 425 4257<br/></a>
                    E-mailadres: <a href="mailto:info@iclicks.nl">info@iclicks.nl</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>

/*Icons*/
.fa-search{
    width: 270px;
    float: left;
    position:relative;
    left:13%;
    color: red;
}
.fa-search a{
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: justify;
}

.fa-calendar-alt{
    width: 270px;
    float: left;
    position:relative;
    left:13%;
    color: red;
}

.fa-calendar-alt a{
    font-size: 20px;
}

.fa-car{
    width: 270px;
    float: left;
    position:relative;
    left:13%;
    color: red;
}

.fa-car a{
    font-size: 20px;
}

.fa-thumbs-up{
    width: 270px;
    float: left;
    position:relative;
    left:13%;
    color: red;
}

.fa-thumbs-up a{
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

hello something like this
https://jsfiddle.net/v4zkq20g/

```
position: relative;
display: block;
margin: 6px -40px;
```

Comment: thats a great one, do you also know how to get them aligned underneath each other centered?

Comment: it has to align like in the picture but needs to stay responsive

Comment: well firstly ur css and html doesn't have or supports any sort of dynamic css such as css grid, bootstraps or flex. So right now if u wanted it to be centre text/images its just by eye

Comment: what do u mean by eye

Comment: the only thing it does wrong now is the div is going over the footer

Comment: ur div structure is hard to locate and separate different divs and classes so i just used margins

Comment: do you mean that u cant find my div in my html file or u mean in the page itself

Comment: no i mean the structure u've done may make it harder to call/identify divs and class in the css.

Comment: can i ask one more thing, when adding more text underneath, the text went right while the icons went left and theyre not aligned anymore, any idea how to fix that

Comment: like i said its by eye so add more or less margin to it think that'll work